# What is the "opposite" of a forgetful functor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, monoid, monoidal-categories

Consider a category $C$ and a monoid $M$. 
Consider a functor $F:C\to M$. It maps the objects of $C$ into the only object of $M$. But I don't want it to map every morphism of $C$ into the identity on $M$. 
If $f$ is a morphism in $C$, I would like in general $F(f)$ to be non-trivial.

Intuitively, this functor forgets *only* the underlying graph, and preserves (some of) the operations. In a way, it is the opposite of a forgetful functor.
Does a functor with such properties have a name?

Comment: I take it, the monoid $M$ you are using is not arbitrary, but dependent on the category $C$? This is not something like the forgetful functor which forgets the structure of the objects and morphisms, but it’s a functor which forgets a lot of the structure of the category itself. The functor you are looking for maybe gives rise to a “forgetful” endofunctor $\mathrm{Cat} → \mathrm{Mon}$, though.

Comment: The "jilted lover functor". It never forgets.

Comment: Here is an example: take as $C$ all the $n$-dimensional vector spaces and their homomorphisms, and take as $M$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its endomorphisms. 
$F$ could be "choosing a base for each space in $C$ and looking at the coordinates".

Comment: Well, in that case, C is equivalent to M. Which is a pretty uncommon situation... you could talk about "the equivalence $F\colon C\to M$", though.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: For any category $C$ and any surjection $\sigma:Ob(C)\to X$ onto a set, there is a category $U$ and a functor $\bar\sigma:C\to U$ such that $Ob(U)=X$, $Ob(\bar\sigma)=\sigma$, and for every functor $f:C\to D$ whose object function factors through $\sigma$ there is a unique functor $f^*:U\to D$ such that $f^*\bar\sigma=f$. This is an exercise from *Topology and Groupoids* by Ronnie Brown, and it generalises a construction for groupoids he describes in the preceding chapter. If you take $X=\{*\}$, you get a universal monoid for $C$.

Comment: My problem comes *exactly* from a groupoid in topology!...I really have to read that book.

Comment: If my comment appeals to you, let me know, so I can make it into an answer.

Comment: Yes please, and please tell me where to find it in Brown's text!

Comment: Please, if you reply to someone's comment, use the notification feature. So if you want that I get notified, include the string `@Stefan` somewhere within your comment. (Sometimes it works without that, but sometimes not)

Comment: I think you have to start the comment with the @name in order for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a construction of a "universal morphism" in Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*, chapter 8.1.  We assume that $G$ is a groupoid, $\sigma:\text{Ob}(G)\to X$ is a set map. Then we can construct a groupoid $U$ whose object set is exactly $X$, and a morphism $\barσ:G\to U$ whose object function is $σ$. The idea is similar to the construction of the free product of groups. We form *words* of different lengths, where a *word of length $n$ from $x$ to $x'$* is a tuple
$$a=(a_n,...,a_1)$$ such that each $a_i$ is in $G(x_i,x_i')$ and
(a) $ x_i'\ne x_{i+1}$
(b) $σx_i'=σx_{i+1}$
(c) $σx_i=x,\ σx_n'=x'$
(d) no $a_i$ is the identity

> Recall how we form a word in the free product of groups $G_i$. We write $a_1a_2...a_n$ where no adjacent elements can be multiplied (which means they come form different $G_i$), and also no $a_1$ is the identity.

We multiply two words by putting them end to end, composing in $G$ and cancelling identities whenever possible.

The resulting groupoid $U_σ(G)$ has as arrows $x\to x'$ words of arbitrary length, where a word of length $0$ is used as identity. If $x\in X\setminusσ(\text{Ob}(G))$, then the only word starting or ending at $x$ is $\mathbf 1_x$, the identity.

the morphism $\barσ:G\to U_σ(G)$ sends $a\ne \mathbf 1$ to $(a)$ and $a=\mathbf 1_{x_1}$ to $()_{σx_1}$

This groupoid has the following universal property:
If $g:G\to K$ is a morphism whose object function factors as $\text{Ob}(g)=\tauσ$, then there is a unique morphism $g^*:U_σ(G)\to K$ such that $g^*\barσ=g$ and $\text{Ob}(g^*)=\tau$.

> Compare this with the definition of the final topology. If $(Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ is a topological space, $X$ is a set, and $s:Y\to X$ is a set map, then there is a topology $\mathcal O_X$ on $X$ making $s$ continuous. For every continuous map $g:Y\to Z$ whose underlying set map factors as $g=\tau s$, there is a unique continuous map $g^*:X\to Z$ such that $g^*s=g$ and $g^*=\tau$ as a set map.

Some interesting cases are when $X=\{*\}$ is a singleton and $σ:\text{Ob}(G)\to X$ the constant function. In that case we obtain a group $UG$ which is universal among all morphisms from $G$ to groups. This is in fact a left adjoint to the inclusion $\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Grpd}$.

The statements and proofs in that chapter carry over almost verbatim to the case of categories instead of groupoids, and monoids instead of groups.

> Coming back to my remark about the free product of groups $(G_i)_{i\in I}$, the *universal group*-functor $U:\mathbf{Grpd}→\mathbf{Grp}$ is left adjoint to the inclusion, so it preserves coproducts. Now the coproduct of $(G_i)_I$ is $\mathbf{Grpd}$ is their disjoint union $\coprod_I G_i$, while the coproduct in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is the free product $\mbox{*}_IG_i$. We then have 
>   $$U\left(\coprod_I G_i\right)=\mbox{*}_I G_i$$ So this gives us the well-known description of the free product of groups. The property (a) then translates to "*Adjacent letters of a word must be from distinct groups*". Property (b) and (c) are automatically satisfied, as all objects are identified.